# Getting deeply nested value in C# Lambda

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I'm trying to get a value from a nested list, but can't figure out how to fetch it. I am looking to get the first occurance of `BnfAmtCmthdSimpleAmount` where `BnfAmtCmthdIsDefault` is `true`.

My best guess returns empty.

```
Products.BenefitPrograms
                    .SelectMany(a => a.BenefitAmountProduct)
                    .FirstOrDefault(b => b.BnfAmtCmthdIsDefault)
                    .BnfAmtCmthdSimpleAmount
```

[image]

Comment: Is your data correct? In the image `Products` is an array, but in your code you're treating it as an object.

Comment: is a class structure available for your json? then add those to your question.

Comment: not tested but you can try this => `var result = Products.SelectMany(x => x.BenefitPrograms.SelectMany(y => y.BenefitPrograms.SelectMany(z => z.BenefitAmountProduct.FirstOrDefault(b => b.BnfAmtCmthdIsDefault == true).BnfAmtCmthdSimpleAmount)));` and let me know.